# InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю систему сохранений в игре:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
public class SaveDataItems : SaveDataRaw
{

    public int[] ints = new int[0];

    public void PrepareForSave()
    {
        string data = JsonUtility.ToJson(ints);
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        ints = JsonUtility.FromJson<int[]>(data);
    }
}
[Serializable]

public class SaveDataRaw 
{
    public string data;
    public void PrepareForSave() { }

    public void Load() { }
}

public class SaveManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static void Save(string fileName, SaveDataRaw data)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath
          + "/"+fileName+".dat");
        data.PrepareForSave();
        bf.Serialize(file, data);
        file.Close();
    }
    public static SaveDataRaw Load(string fileName)
    {

        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + fileName + ".dat"))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file =
            File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + fileName + ".dat", FileMode.Open);
            SaveDataRaw data = (SaveDataRaw)bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();
            return data;
        }
        else return new SaveDataRaw();
    }
}
```

Но если я пытаюсь загрузить список предметов

```
SaveDataItems save = (SaveDataItems)SaveManager.Load("Items");
save.Load();
```

То при запуске появляется ошибка, подскажите что можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static SaveDataRaw Load(string fileName)
```

Метод возвращает `SaveDataRaw`, а вы пытаетесь его скастовать в `SaveDataItems`.

```
(SaveDataItems)SaveManager.Load("Items");
```

То есть вы пытаетесь привести тип родителя `SaveDataRaw data` к наследнику.

Такой каст невозможен. Можно только наследника к родителю, либо наследника, ранее поднятого к родителю опустить обратно к себе.

Вот так можно

```
SaveDataItems item = new SaveDataItems();
SaveDataRaw cast = (SaveDataRaw)item;
```

И вот так можно

```
SaveDataItems item = new SaveDataItems();
SaveDataRaw upcast = (SaveDataRaw)item;
SaveDataItems downcast = (SaveDataItems)upcast;
```

А вот так нельзя

```
SaveDataRaw item = new SaveDataRaw();
SaveDataItems cast = (SaveDataItems)item; // InvalidCastException
```

То есть здесь важен не тип ссылки на объект, и тип самого объекта под ссылкой, который создан с помощью `new`.

Comment: Я поискал и нашел что можно сделать [собственный каст](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.37.php)